# Quartz scheduler - allow parallel job execution

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz

I am working on Quartz Scheduler and I don't know how to run jobs in parallel.
Is there something from config file that can allow me to do that ?

Comment: Can you not find anything on google?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More details will help answer your question. But in general, a job can be executed in parallel if there are multiple triggers that are getting fired at the same time that reference this job. This is a feature that is provided by quartz.